# Remove background image from div

Tags: css

I have css declaration like this

```
#first, #second, #third {
 font-size:1em;
 background: url('path/to/image') no-repeat;

}
```

Next I want to remove background only for #third;

I have tried

```
#third {
background:none;
}
```

But it doesn`t work.

Comment: Is your second declaration below the original declaration?

Comment: Are you sure you want a descendant selector?

Comment: Your first selector: `#first, #second #third`. Are you sure you don't mean `#first, #second, #third`, with the extra comma?

Comment: It is typo. It should looks #first, #second, #third

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first selector is more specific than the second one, so it has priority.

To solve this, you can make the second selector equally specific by changing it to `#second #third`.
If that won't select the same elements, your design is flawed; element IDs should be unique.

Alternatively, you can add `!important` to the second `background` rule to force it to override the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do this?

```
#first, #second {
 font-size:1em;
 background: url('path/to/image') no-repeat;

}
#third {
font-size:1em;
}
```

Comment: That's not the same.  Read his selector carefully.

Comment: @SLaks I am pretty sure he mean `#first, #second, #third` if not, I agree with you

Comment: My mistake. It is #fist, #second, #third

Answer (score 1):

So why not just remove third from the first style declarations and make a seperate

```
#third {
   font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because `#second #third` is more specific than `#third`.  Did you mean to group `#second` and `#third` together, or did you forget a comma?

It sounds like that wasn't what you intended, so this should fix it:

```
#first, #second, #third {
    font-size:1em;
    background: url('path/to/image') no-repeat;
}
```

Note the comma - that's all it takes.  Your `#second` element should also be styled correctly with this edit.

Also, did you place the separate declaration for #third after the other set of code?  Order matters, and it would need to come after the declaration of `#first`, `#second` and `#third`.